# How to reload to payment step in Onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

How can I reload Onepage Checkout to specific step specifically payment step when payment is not approved

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. This depends very much on how the payment method works and cannot be answered without more information. Which payment method / extension are you using? What does currently happen when payment is not approved? Please edit the question to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to identify whether the payment is approved or not and based on that you can execute below JS code:

```
checkout.gotoSection('payment')
```

You can open any step by using the `gotoSection` method. Below are the step names you should pass as instead of "payment" to open other sections.

`login`
`billing`,
`shipping`
`shipping_method` and 
`review`

Answer (score 0):

To get you started for a possible solution:

You can jump to sections using the javascript function gotoSection

```
checkout.gotoSection('payment');
```

If you want jump directly to payment section you need to save data for shipping/billing beforehand and trigger the load of the payment block.